# GSON/JSON Deserialize of a singleton

Tags: java, json, singleton, deserialization, gson

I have a following Singleton class:

```
public class AuthenticatedUser extends User {

    private volatile static AuthenticatedUser instance;

    public static AuthenticatedUser getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
                synchronized (AuthenticatedUser.class) {
                    instance = new AuthenticatedUser();
                }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private AuthenticatedUser() {

    }
}
```

I deserialize as follow:

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent());

User user = new Gson().fromJson(reader, User.class);
AuthenticatedUser aus = AuthenticatedUser.getInstance();
aus.setId(user.getId());
aus.setUsername(user.getUsername());
aus.setPassword(user.getPassword());
aus.setEmail(user.getPassword());
aus.setFullName(user.getFullName());
```

My question: How  can I deserialize this directly to a Singleton?

Comment: What do you mean? You are deserialising into the singleton.

Comment: Well If I change User.class to AuthenticatUser.class it isn't making an instance, how to solve that? Just put instance = this or instance = getInstance() in private constructor?

Comment: I think you have stumbled across the exact reason why [singletons are evil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/138012/2071828)...

Comment: Ok, I think that is lecture a bit above my head. Well I just need to store the User instance in my application so I can access it from multiple places when needed, So Singleton was the only option I found. Will have to rethink about this.

Answer (score 2):

Since Gson uses reflection - it ignores the private/public instructions which are checked at compile time, and therefore it can create a new object. However, if you want this object to be your singleton's instance, you will need to manually set it.
here is an example:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();

// Serializing
AuthenticatedUser user = AuthenticatedUser.getInstance();
user.setUsername("me");
String json = gson.toJson(user);

// Desesializing
AuthenticatedUser user2 = gson.fromJson(json, AuthenticatedUser.class);
user2.setInstance(); // this is important!
String username = AuthenticatedUser.getInstance().getUsername();
```